# browse a file from my PC with selenuim

Tags: selenium

I want to write a selenium program on a site which I need as part of the process to browse a file from the operating system. How can I do that?

Comment: Seems not possible, Selenium have control over the HTML page only

Comment: Could you provide an example. You haven't provided much detail

Comment: You can't do it with Selenium. One option is to use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use Selenium to open a html file on local, it's easy to do. 
1. open the html file on browser 
2. copy the url in browser address, it should be like:

```
file:///C:/workspace/js-projects/tey/protractor-cucumber-tey/reports/cucumber_report.html
```

3. put above url in browser.get()

Better way it's to caclcute the html file absolute path in your scritp dynamically (rather than hard code), then prefix with file://// on the path, possible need to replace '\' to '/' in path.

Comment: I wrote this: driver.findElement(By.id("dupload")).sendKeys("C:\\SLT file\\(5) Libi Ziser.html"); and i dont see that something happens.The drop/browse window is stiil stays open.

Comment: Could you clarify you want to upload a file or open a html file on local?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you mean by "browse a file from the operating system."

If you mean choosing file to upload, you can.

see link below

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.openqa.selenium.remote.LocalFileDetector

Comment: I mean browse a file from my PC

Comment: Why do you need to browse file ?? I think you should provide more information in order to get right answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to browse a file in the local machine with the OpenFileDialog (not sure if this is what you are looking for), in my case, I created an autoIt script, building it as .exe and then call it from Java code (or any programming language you are using with Selenium).

[image]

I found an exmaple, it might works: https://github.com/ellysh/autoit-examples/blob/master/Helpfile/FileOpenDialog.au3

Comment: dont know why the answer is down graded :D